# Calculate last lowest value using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

Data1:

```
ID Value 
2   114    
3   108    
4   107    
5   113    
6   112    
7   106    
8   109
```

Data Required In Power BI(DAX):

```
ID Value last_recovery_id
2   114    5
3   108    4
4   107    X
5   113    6
6   112    7
7   106    X
8   109
```

Basically I want to know the last id after which the price went higher.

Comment: Why it is X for id 4 and 7?

Comment: Because there is higher values between  106 and 107.I want to see what is the last id after which the value was recovered.

Comment: Can you explain the logic bit more?

Comment: Consider a value 114.I want to know what is the latest data in the series after which the value went higher.I.e recovery period.Number of rows/taken to recover the price. It will search for the nearest closest value which is lower than 114.Is it understandable.(just ignore the for the time being,consider value of X as ID 7)

Comment: Is there any condition like - ID > current_id?

Comment: What do you mean by "after"? there is no timestamp and the iDs are not sorted in a progressive way: the first rows shows the last_id is greater than current ID

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below measure-

```
last_recovery_id = 
var current_row_value = min(your_table_name[Value])
var current_row_id = min(your_table_name[ID])
var previous_max_value = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[Value]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Value] < current_row_value
        && your_table_name[ID] > current_row_id
    )
)

var prevous_id =  
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[id]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Value] = previous_max_value
        && your_table_name[ID] > current_row_id
    )
)

RETURN IF(prevous_id = BLANK(),"X", prevous_id)
```

The output is-

[image]